# Visual Studio CPU-sampling enter/exit method

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiler

While profiling my application in Visual Studio 2013 (probably applies to other versions as well), I noticed the application consumes cycles upon enter/exit of a method. Where do these cycles come from, and how can I eliminate them eventually?

Below is an example of a profiling session I did recently. While the percentages are rather low (0.9% and <0.1%) in this screenshot, I experienced it fluctuates between 0% and 25% per method.

[image: sample profile]

Or

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These cycles can come from calling the **constructors/destructors of local objects**.

To test this theory you could create a class, that r**uns a computational loop in the destructor** and *make sure the compiler does not optimize it away*. Then in your function code, create an object of that class on the stack (without allocating it dynamically). When the function exits, the destructor of the local object will be called, thus - your loop. You should see a consistent cycle count.

Also **passing/extracting arguments and saving stack** according to calling conventions might add some more cycles upon enter and exit.

If you get 25% values that's probably because you have low amount of work in the function's body.

Comment: Shouldn't I able to see the percentage on the line that causes the actual load? Eg. `T::GetTypeId` that uses copy/move causes the same line to highlight, and not the first brace of the method?

Comment: You could try and split the return line in 2. Make a temp variable that is the getComponent(T::...) result and in the second line return it via static cast.

Comment: So far so good, but still 0.5% upon enter/exit (see additional screenshot in OP). Where does that come from (just interested in these things, I hope you don't mind)?

Comment: No mind at all. In your code, typeId, component and typedComponent are local variables. Once you get out of the functions, they become out of scope so they need to be destroyed. That could be a cause. Also the function's calling convention involves stack saving and putting parameters. This can cause enter function overhead.